# Verify files on disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I use a number of suspect drives as 2nd backup drives - by suspect I mean they show up as yellow in Crystal Disk.

I use these to backup GOOD disks that are themselves backups - and not on anything critical for which I have two GOOD copies.

What I'd like to do, after filling one of these disks up, is verify it to check all the files are still readable.

The quickest method appears to be copying all the files somewhere else, but I don't always have space on my internal HDD for this, and copying to another external slows the process down.

Is there a method (Windows 7) where I can check a file is readable, but not actually copy it anywhere?

I know I can also use chkdsk with a surface scan, but this takes ages - and checks the whole disk when files may only occupy part of it.

Comment: This seems a bit of a pointless exercise… why do a redundant backup to something that's only got a 50/50 chance of being any use? It sounds like a complete waste of effort. If time is money, buy an online backup strategy for your redundancy. It will cost about 2-4 hours of your time a year.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable"? Errors inside the files themselves are copied as if there was no error at all. Only a program used to open a file will be able to tell you if it is truly "readable". Filesystems are designed to be resilient to errors and correct themselves too. So if the error is "outside" the file (in the filesystem or disk), Windows will detect that automatically and relocate the file. I think your idea of "readable" may be ensuring that files are *stored* correctly, this is what chkdsk is used for with NTFS filesystems.

Comment: @Romen - the only errors I'm worried about here are disk errors - if the file can be read back from the disk without error, then it will be fine.
Yes I know you can configure xcopy to read a file and continue on error, but that's not the same as NOT knowing whether or not a disk error has occurred.

Comment: @Romen: Your statement about filesystems resilience is wrong. Windows will only locate a file elsewhere if the sector has already been labelled as faulty. There's nothing to stop Windows writing to a faulty sector that hasn't yet been flagged as such by the HDD - hence my wish to check I can read the files back.

Comment: Yes, the file explorer and the underlying disk operations may not be able to automatically recover from bad sectors. The bad sectors are detected by `chkdsk`, which is automatically run by Windows when it has a reason to. So if you want to use NTFS but refuse to wait for `chkdsk`, I don't see any way to avoid the bad sectors. My statement that "filesystems are designed to be resilient to errors" is not just about NTFS though. Maybe you would benefit from the error-correction provided by using a [different filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS).

Comment: So your backup strategy is to have a “good” backup, but you also use what you yourself describe as “suspect drives” as some kind of secondary backup? The whole purpose of backups is peace of mind, not stress. The reality is white you claim — in the comments — that these drives have never failed on you in 20 years yet you believe they are “suspect drives” the question in your mind still exists that they *might* die. Honestly, cheap hard drives are very plentiful nowadays. For $75 to $85  (USD) you can get a brand new 4TB Seagate USB drive. This question is based on OCD; not common sense.

Comment: What - no that's complete nonsense @Romen.

1) Chkdsk never runs automatically on an external drive
2) Chkdsk never runs with a surface scan (which detects bad sectors) unless you specifically tell it to

And no - it's nothing to do with the file system. No file system BY DEFAULT reads data written to disk back immediately. 

FYI - you should read up on what bad sectors are and how they're caused and identifed:
https://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Comment: Am I missing something here with your question? *"Is there a method (Windows 7) where I can check a file is readable, but not actually copy it anywhere?"* Surely the answer would be to try and open it into the correct program. If it's a Word doc for example, open it in Word and see if it's readable.

Comment: @chris Rogers - yes you're missing a lot - opening a file in a program only reads a tiny fraction of it. I'm mostly dealing with 1-25Gb archives.

Answer (score 1):

[CD Reader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aekcdreader/) is a free, open source (GPLv3) application that can be used to **verify files** for errors. It's primarily designed to help you scan CDs and discover any unreadable files.

It adopts a classical-looking interface made from a standard window with a built-in file navigator to easily track down a specific drive or directory to verify it for reading errors. For this operation, it's possible to use a big buffer.

On scan completion, CD Reader reveals the total number of files and folders in the current location, along with the size and elapsed time. If it identifies any errors, it shows the full path of the problematic file, along with the error's position and description. For example, a file cannot be opened because it's currently being used by another process.

[image: CD Reader]